# Build 3 services with docker-compose but start only 2 containers

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I am starting with docker-compose so i do have a noob question. I want to build three services, but having two running permantly and one that will run via contrab. Is it possible to build the image of the three and just run two with docker-compose (build/up)? Or should i have the a docker-compose to build and run the two permanent ones, and manualy build the third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a script that wraps both of these commands

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up service1 service2
```